# Получить информацию о параметрах URL

Tags: javascript

```
function URL(url) {
    if (....) {
        var url = url+'&key=1234'; // В url есть GET параметры (склейка параметров)
    } else {
        var url = url+'?key=1234'; // В url нет GET параметров
    }
}
```

Есть функция URL. Из этой функции всегда передается GET параметр **key=1234** он добавляется к действующей ссылке. Но происходит проблема, когда в **url**  уже есть GET параметры и тогда ссылка формируется неправильно и вклеянный параметр из функции учитываться не будет: `//example.com?parmetr=1234?key=1234`

Поэтому, как из JS проверить существуют ли GET параметры в url и тогда уже выполнить условие из функции?

Comment: `document.location.search`

Answer (score 1):

```
function URL(url) {
var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);

    if (queryString ) {
        var url = url+'&key=1234'; // В url есть GET параметры (склейка параметров)
    } else {
        var url = url+'?key=1234'; // В url нет GET параметров
    }
}
```